# WCF function doesn't show in VSTO project

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2012, vsto

I have a problem with a WCF service. I am developing an Excel addin and it will communicate with a SQL Server database through a WCF service.

I have 1 procedure and 1 function in my service.

Procedure works fine, it works in WCF test client and Excel showing the result (rows from table) in ListBox.

Problem is the function. The function is working in the WCF test client, but intellisense in VS in the Excel solution doesn't show the function as a possibility. So I can't call it.

This is code from `AdminService.svc` (getPlan working fine, getAutentication doesn't)

```
public class AdminService : IAdminService
{
    string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PlanDatabase"].ToString();

    public List<Plan> getPlan()
    {
        List<Plan> plans = new List<Plan>();

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection))
        {
            using (SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand("SELECT categoryid, categoryname FROM Production.Categories", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = query.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Plan plan = new Plan();
                    plan.id = int.Parse(reader[0].ToString());
                    plan.name = reader[1].ToString();
                    plans.Add(plan);
                }
            }
        }

        return plans.ToList();
    }

    public bool getAutentication(string login, string psw){
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection))
        {
            using (SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand("SELECT dbo.VerifyAccount('"+login+"','"+psw+"')", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = query.ExecuteReader();
                reader.Read();

                if (int.Parse(reader[0].ToString()) == 1)
                { 
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is `IAdminService.cs`:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IAdminService
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool getAutentication(string login, string psw);

    [OperationContract]
    List<Plan> getPlan();    
}
```

and this is code for my Form in Excel Addin

```
 AdminServiceClient connection = new AdminServiceClient();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.listBox1.DataSource = connection.getPlan().ToList();
        this.listBox1.DisplayMember = "name"; 
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool pass = false;
        this.Hide();
        MessageBox.Show(pass.ToString());
    }
```

Service is referenced in Excel Addin. Connection is correct, because getPlan is showing and working. But if I want to use this command in `Button1_click`:

```
pass = connection.getAutentication('login','password')
```

VS tells me the function isn't defined.

Do you see some kind of error in my code? I think it should normally work, but I don't know why it doesn't.

Thanks very much for your answers!

Comment: sorry it may sound silly or may not be helpful. If you added your method later update your reference.

Comment: Yeah, I just tried it for myself and thats the problem. I thought, that VS does it automatically when rebuilding project, thank you!